# Dirac operator in Generalized Geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, spin-geometry

I am wondering how the Dirac operator can be built in the context of Hichin's generalized geometry.

In particular, I have the following questions:

- On a spin manifold, is the conventional spin connection replaced by a generalized one that has two coordinate indices?
- If so, does this generalized spin connection behave as a non-Abelian $\text{SO}(3,1)$ "B-field" (called also Kalb-Ramond field in physics)?

Comment: For those interested, an answer from physicists to this has been given here on PhysicsOverflow: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/27324/dirac-operator-in-generalized-geometry?show=27365#a27365